# JavaScript: Is this replacement of special characters correct?

Tags: javascript

Our web application went wrong couple of times because of copy-pasting text from other application. Always the saved ASCII control characters were the root cause (e.g. 0x1A). I would like to eliminate all the possible control characters from the input string except for newline and tabulator. I created the following code:

```
var originalString, newString;
newString = originalString.replace(/[\x00-\x08\x0B-\x1F\x7F]+/g, '');
```

So I keep the tabulator (0x09) and newline (0x0A). My tests are all fine, but I would like to be sure before adding this code to our application.

Is that the one I want? Is it correct? Or should be extended? Or this should be done rather in the backend?

Comment: Any restriction you do in the front-end you most definitely need to do in the back end.  The back-end is the important part, the front-end just improves usability for good actors.  Rather than excluding characters, why don't you explicity set what is permitted (e.g., `/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-/`) -- this decision changes if you want to allow for non-ASCII characters

Comment: Why not remove all characters below 0x20 ? (except 0x09 and 0x0A) Also do you care about the \r character?

Comment: @vol7ron That would be a lot more complicated if they intended to support all utf text

Comment: "vol7ron" we allow input of any UNICODE character, so I would like to really eliminate only the control chars
"zoran404" basically that's what I'm doing... removing chars from dec(0) to dec(31) except for tab and newline and also that DEL character which has code 0x7F. Regarding CarriageReturn - I couldn't input that character, so I don't care about that

Comment: @zoran404 yep :) that’s what I meant by non-ASCII. It all depends on implementation and in this case doesn’t make sense.